# Como lançar exceção personalizada T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, exceção, tsql

Tenho uma tigger para validação de CPF, e quero lançar uma exceção caso o CPF informado seja inválido.

Sobre o lançamento de exceções estive lendo essa [publicação](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manub22/2013/12/30/new-throw-statement-in-sql-server-2012-vs-raiserror/), mas nos exemplos do autor ele simplesmente provoca uma exceção que já existe no sistema (Division by zero) e simplesmente relança essa exceção.

Mas o que eu quero é lançar uma exceção nova, uma exceção que não exista no sistema, tipo, uma exceção `CpfInvalid`.

Answer (score 2):

Matheus, o *SQL SERVER* não tem uma função para validação de *CPF ou CNPJ*, esses tipos de números são padrões Brasileiros e não são aplicados para outros países, por isso uma função desse tipo não teria uso para muitos usuários desse banco.

Você tem a opção de lança a exceção através do [BEGIN TRY END TRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175976.aspx) ou usar o [RAISERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178592.aspx) para retorna uma mensagem de erro.

O ideal nesse caso é que você trate sua validação do lado do cliente (EX; JavaScript) e na aplicação (EX; C#, JAVA), não use o banco de dados para esse tipo de validação, isso tem um custo de processamento de ida e volta ao banco, quando sua aplicação poderia valida facilmente.

Comment: Entendo as questões de fazer as validações na aplicação. Mas, atendo-se ao tema de sobre fazer isso no db. Não vejo razões para usar `BEGIN TRY END TRY` pois como você mesmo citou uma exceção de `CpfInvalido` não existe no SQL Server, eu já sabia disso.
Eu não vejo pq usar `BEGIN TRY END TRY` pelo mesmo motivo que eu acho infelizes os exemplos da publicação que citei.
Ou seja, nos exemplo da publicação o autor não faz nenhum tratamento, apenas relança a exceção com um texto a mais.
Como no SQLServer não existe exceção para `CpfInvalid` `TRY CATCH` é inútil.

cont.....

Comment: Não quero tratar uma exceção que não existe, quero apenas lançar uma, e deixar que exploda na aplicação.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva , o RAISERROR pode retorna uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva,  Retorna mensagem bonitas na aplicação não são uma boa, isso só esconderia o erro real que esta ocorrendo, a forma que o altor faz, descrito na pergunta não esta errada, ele retorna a exceção de forma correta, não existe erro algum nisso.

Comment: No meu entendimento o que o autor faz é apenas capturar e relançar. Isso não é o mesmo que não fazer nenhum tratamento?
Sobre o `RAISERROR` vi que ele está depreciado e sendo substituído por `THROW`, onde a [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee677615.aspx) diz ter três parâmetros `error_number` `message` e `state`.
Minha dúvida agora é se os valores de `error_number` e `state` são de livre escolha do programador.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva, não são bem de livre escolha, o [ERROR_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175069.aspx) é capturado no bloco de tratamento assim como a [ERROR_MESSAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190358.aspx) e o [ERROR_STATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180031.aspx), mas você pode mostrar mensagem da forma como você deseja, mas como falei anteriormente isso só esconderia o real erro.